# Switch Javascript fullscreen button when ESC is pressed

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a button to go in fullscreen mode, the buttons says **ON** or **OFF**, which works fine:

```
<div class="onoffswitch" onclick="fullscreen()">
    <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch">
    <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">
        <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
        <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
    </label>
</div>
```

But when I am in fulscreen and I press ESC, the button still says **OFF**
So I tried to simulate a click effect:

```
document.getElementById("myonoffswitch").click();
```

I thought my problem was solved, but then I found out that the `.click` was also triggered when the fullscreen button is clicked. It will trigger the button twice.

Then I tried this to prevent the normal click reaction:

```
<div class="onoffswitch" onclick="fullscreen(); return false;">
```

But then nothing at all happend, the `.click` did not change the button anymore. 
Though I understand why: The `.click` is just like a normal click and the normal click is returned as false.

I have searched and tried a lot, but I didn't find anything that worked for me.

This is my javascript at the moment:

```
function fullscreen() {
    if ((document.fullScreenElement && document.fullScreenElement !== null) ||
        (!document.mozFullScreen && !document.webkitIsFullScreen)) {
        if (document.documentElement.requestFullScreen) {
            document.documentElement.requestFullScreen();
        } else if (document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen) {
            document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen();
        } else if (document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
            document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullScreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
        }
    } else {
        if (document.cancelFullScreen) {
            document.cancelFullScreen();
        } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
            document.mozCancelFullScreen();
        } else if (document.webkitCancelFullScreen) {
            document.webkitCancelFullScreen();
        }
    }
}

document.addEventListener('fullscreenchange', exitHandler);
document.addEventListener('webkitfullscreenchange', exitHandler);
document.addEventListener('mozfullscreenchange', exitHandler);
document.addEventListener('MSFullscreenChange', exitHandler);

function exitHandler() {
// Any fullscreen change will trigger this function
// Normalscreen to fullscreen or fullscreen to normalscreen
// with the button or with ESC-key.
    if (!document.fullscreenElement && !document.webkitIsFullScreen && !document.mozFullScreen && !document.msFullscreenElement) {

    document.getElementById("myonoffswitch").click();
        // This event is always trickered, but it's meant to be trickered when ESCAPE is used,    

    } 
}
```

I made a fiddle but it doesn't work, I still post it because it's a more easy way to use the javascript: [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yyd29cqf/1/)

And Because the fiddle didn't work, I will put it on my website untill the problem is solved: *problem is solved*

Let me know if something is not clear,
thanks

**[EDIT]** 

I solved it by myself 

 [Updated JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yyd29cqf/2/)

Comment: Hi, did you see that the problem is also here without pressing escape? I think that the problem is obvious. When you go first in fullscreen you do not have added yet the `exitHandler`, so everything work fine even exiting using escape. However once in fullscreen mode and after detecting a change (by clicking the button), your `exitHandler` trigger a second `click` event on the button which toggle back to its same position.. Let me now if I am not clear enough..

Comment: I think I understand what you are saying but,  I think I was not clear enough: The script works really well. I'm just trying to accomplish something I don't know how to accomplish. My point was: The button click event in the javascript DOES work when ESC is pressed. But it also DOES work when the button is clicked so that the button is clicked twice. One time by the user, one time by javascript. I don't want this to happen, but I don't know how to let it work.

Comment: @SanjiBukai Do we understand each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suddenly saw that my switch button is just a checkbox so I tried this: `document.getElementById("myonoffswitch").checked = false;`
And it seems to work really well.

Answer (score 1):

```
**Please try this code** It's Working fine.

<style>
.btn-toggle {
  margin: 0 4rem;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  border: none;
  height: 1.5rem;
  width: 3rem;
  border-radius: 1.5rem;
  color: #6b7381;
  background: #bdc1c8;
}
.btn-toggle:focus,
.btn-toggle.focus,
.btn-toggle:focus.active,
.btn-toggle.focus.active {
  outline: none;
}
.btn-toggle:before,
.btn-toggle:after {
  line-height: 1.5rem;
  width: 4rem;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  transition: opacity .25s;
}
.btn-toggle:before {
  content: 'Off';
  left: -4rem;
}
.btn-toggle:after {
  content: 'On';
  right: -4rem;
  opacity: .5;
}
.btn-toggle > .handle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.1875rem;
  left: 0.1875rem;
  width: 1.125rem;
  height: 1.125rem;
  border-radius: 1.125rem;
  background: #fff;
  transition: left .25s;
}
.btn-toggle.active {
  transition: background-color 0.25s;
}
.btn-toggle.active > .handle {
  left: 1.6875rem;
  transition: left .25s;
}
.btn-toggle.active:before {
  opacity: .5;
}
.btn-toggle.active:after {
  opacity: 1;
}

.btn-toggle:before,
.btn-toggle:after {
  color: #6b7381;
}
.btn-toggle.active {
  background-color: #29b5a8;
}
.btn-toggle.btn-lg {
  margin: 0 5rem;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  border: none;
  height: 2.5rem;
  width: 5rem;
  border-radius: 2.5rem;
}
.btn-toggle.btn-lg:focus,
.btn-toggle.btn-lg.focus,
.btn-toggle.btn-lg:focus.active,
.btn-toggle.btn-lg.focus.active {
  outline: none;
}
.btn-toggle.btn-lg:before,
.btn-toggle.btn-lg:after {
  line-height: 2.5rem;
  width: 5rem;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 1rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  transition: opacity .25s;
}
.btn-toggle.btn-lg:before {
  content: 'Off';
  left: -5rem;
}
.btn-toggle.btn-lg:after {
  content: 'On';
  right: -5rem;
  opacity: .5;
}
.btn-toggle.btn-lg > .handle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.3125rem;
  left: 0.3125rem;
  width: 1.875rem;
  height: 1.875rem;
  border-radius: 1.875rem;
  background: #fff;
  transition: left .25s;
}
.btn-toggle.btn-lg.active {
  transition: background-color 0.25s;
}
.btn-toggle.btn-lg.active > .handle {
  left: 2.8125rem;
  transition: left .25s;
}
.btn-toggle.btn-lg.active:before {
  opacity: .5;
}
.btn-toggle.btn-lg.active:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
.btn-toggle.btn-lg.btn-sm:before,
.btn-toggle.btn-lg.btn-sm:after {
  line-height: 0.5rem;
  color: #fff;
  letter-spacing: .75px;
  left: 0.6875rem;
  width: 3.875rem;
}
.btn-toggle.btn-lg.btn-sm:before {
  text-align: right;
}
.btn-toggle.btn-lg.btn-sm:after {
  text-align: left;
  opacity: 0;
}
.btn-toggle.btn-lg.btn-sm.active:before {
  opacity: 0;
}
.btn-toggle.btn-lg.btn-sm.active:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
.btn-toggle.btn-lg.btn-xs:before,
.btn-toggle.btn-lg.btn-xs:after {
  display: none;
}
</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
Fullscreen:  
<div class="col-sm-5">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-toggle myswitch" data-toggle="button" aria-pressed="false" onclick="fullscreen()" autocomplete="off">
    <div class="handle"></div>
    </button>
</div>
<script>
function fullscreen() {
    if ((document.fullScreenElement && document.fullScreenElement !== null) ||
        (!document.mozFullScreen && !document.webkitIsFullScreen)) {
        if (document.documentElement.requestFullScreen) {
            document.documentElement.requestFullScreen();
        } else if (document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen) {
            document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen();
        } else if (document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
            document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullScreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
        }
    } else {
        if (document.cancelFullScreen) {
            document.cancelFullScreen();
        } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
            document.mozCancelFullScreen();
        } else if (document.webkitCancelFullScreen) {
            document.webkitCancelFullScreen();
        }
       $('.myswitch').removeClass('active')
    }
}

document.addEventListener('fullscreenchange', exitHandler);
document.addEventListener('webkitfullscreenchange', exitHandler);
document.addEventListener('mozfullscreenchange', exitHandler);
document.addEventListener('MSFullscreenChange', exitHandler);

function exitHandler() {
    if (!document.fullscreenElement && !document.webkitIsFullScreen && !document.mozFullScreen && !document.msFullscreenElement) {
        $('.myswitch').removeClass('active')
    document.getElementById("myonoffswitch").click();
        console.log("this is not fullscreen");
        $(".onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-inner").css("margin-right","");
    } else {
        console.log("this fullscreen");
        $(".onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-inner").css("margin-left","");
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. But it's not my style anymore and I do like to use plaine javascript. So I will now try to adopt this into my script. Can you maybe help me?

Comment: I have found a different solution bcs of the inside you gave me. Thanks